# Is there an easy way to find duplicate spirits?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

I want to dismiss duplicate spirits. Is there an easy way to find them? The only method I've been using so far is to sort them by name and just sift through them manually, which is extremely tedious. Is there an easier way?

Side note: the manual checking has the additional downside that you might not recognize duplicate spirits if one of them has been enhanced.

Comment: Not an answer to your main question, but for your side note, you could favorite any spirits that are enhanced and wish to keep. You can't dismiss favorited spirits

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the "dismiss spirits" menu that you were in there's a sorting option for "By Number Obtained (High to Low)" which makes it easy to dismiss all of the duplicates.

[image: pic of the menu]

Comment: Wait... what? That's what it means? I thought that was referring to the level!